# How to add a text on video as overlay while the video is in pause state in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, mediaelement

I'am using MediElement to play videos.Now I want to add a text on video when it is in pause state. How is it possible?

```
 <MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Stretch="Fill"  MediaOpened="videoMediaElement_MediaOpened" CurrentStateChanged="Media_State_Changed" >
 <MediaElement.TransportControls>
 <MediaTransportControls Background="Red" Foreground="White" IsStopButtonVisible="True" IsStopEnabled="True" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="True" IsPlaybackRateEnabled="True" IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="True" IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True" IsFastForwardEnabled="True" IsFastRewindButtonVisible="True" IsFastRewindEnabled="True" />
 </MediaElement.TransportControls>
 </MediaElement>

private async void Media_State_Changed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
        {
       //write  a text here
        }
     }
```

Comment: Just add TextBlock in XAML after MediaElement and change it's Visibility

Comment: I want to display the text on the video.Not outside of mediaelement

Comment: You may set text offset or do you mean with some effects?

Comment: text offset?how is it?no need any effects.only need to display a text over the video while pausing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Stretch="Fill"  MediaOpened="videoMediaElement_MediaOpened" CurrentStateChanged="Media_State_Changed" >
            <MediaElement.TransportControls>
                <MediaTransportControls Background="Red" Foreground="White" IsStopButtonVisible="True" IsStopEnabled="True" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="True" IsPlaybackRateEnabled="True" IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="True" IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True" IsFastForwardEnabled="True" IsFastRewindButtonVisible="True" IsFastRewindEnabled="True" />
            </MediaElement.TransportControls>
        </MediaElement>

        <TextBlock Text="asdf" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

You may also change parent `Grid` to `Canvas` and set `Canvas.Top`/`Canvas.Left` to `TextBlock`. Or just use `Margin`.